# Send multiple tags with UIButton in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Im suffering from sending two tags to a function to show `UIActivityViewController` and share the cell data, well before i used to send one value at a time and within a single `UIButton`:

```
cell.sharefb.tag = indexPath.row
cell.sharefb.addTarget(self, action: "showAlert:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

But now I've implemented sections in my `UITableView` so my array is like :

```
Array[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

One of them (section or row) is not enough at a time, i need to send both to my function ? how can i do that ?

```
func showAlert(sender:AnyObject){
    // i want to use it like :
    Array[sender.sectionvalue][sender.rowvalue]
}
```

Comment: better answer
cell.buyButton.titleLabel.tag = 3

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498064/pass-multiple-parameters-to-addtarget

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could subClass UIButton and add properties for the data you need eg

```
class MyButton : UIButton {

var row : Int?
var section : Int?

}
```

you can then set those properties, and in your showAlert function you can get them back and use:

```
 func showAlert(sender:AnyObject){

    let theButton = sender as! MyButton

    let section = theButton.section
    let row = theButton.row

    }
```

**Edit: Added where to set the button as per comment requested:**

In your StoryBoard, make sure that your button is of type MyButton (and not UIButton anymore).

and then where you used to set the tag, don't use the tag but set the properties. So replace this code :

```
cell.sharefb.tag = indexPath.row
cell.sharefb.addTarget(self, action: "showAlert:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

with:

```
 cell.sharefb.row = indexPath.row
 cell.sharefb.section = indexPath.section
 cell.sharefb.addTarget(self, action: "showAlert:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: I've just made it while you where posting, thanks anyway !