# How to pass multiple parameters addTarget?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to pass two parameters. How can i pass by `addTarget` **action**. If it possible what changes i need to perform?

This is my current code.

```
button.tag = numbers[index];
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){
     print(sender.tag)
}
```

Comment: I hope this answer useful :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498064/pass-multiple-parameters-to-addtarget?rq=1

Comment: i use ActionKit project for this kind of problems.With closures mostly you don't need to carry parameters around
https://github.com/ActionKit/ActionKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more then one perimeter pass then you can use a `objc_setAssociatedObject`.
Any thing will be pass like **Dictionary,Array,String,Int.**

```
import ObjectiveC

extension UIButton {
private struct AssociatedKeys {
    static var WithValue = "KeyValue"
}

@IBInspectable var withValue: String? {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.WithValue) as? String
    }
    set {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(
                self,
                &AssociatedKeys.WithValue,
                newValue as NSString?,
                objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
            )
        }
    }
}
}
```

You need to use above extension:-

**import ObjectiveC**

```
button.tag = numbers[index];
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    //set velue
   button.withVelue = "1,2,3,4"

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){

     print(sender.withVelue)
}
```

Comment: It say:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Thanks. It was working :) And I have a one question. sender.withValue is printing Optional("1,2,3,4"). How can I remove Optional()?

Comment: Oh. Int(sender.withValue) is working :) Thanks @mitul marsonia